# Quick & easy ways to compile binaries for Debian/Ubuntu from Arch Linux

Tags: debian, ubuntu, arch-linux, compiling

I use Arch Linux as my main OS. Sometimes (in [CTFs](https://ctftime.org/)), I need to compile a program for a Debian/Ubuntu OS and upload it to the target machine since they may not have a compiler binary (sand-boxed, not installed, etc) and have no internet connection.

I'd rather not have to install & boot a whole new VM just for compiling some binaries, and I'm not sure how well Docker would work since I'm an Arch/Manjaro kernel.

What are some quick & easy ways to compile binaries for Ubuntu/Debian systems from an Arch Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to run Ubuntu/Debian in an LXC-Container and build your stuff from there.

Should be way faster than booting a VM.